# Running on iPhone OS 4.0, my app no longer loads localized resource

Tags: localization, ios4

I have an app for OS 3.0. It is localized for Chinese (in addition to the base support of English).

It works perfectly on all devices with OS 3.0, 3.1.x, even on iPad with 3.2. That is, when I select Chinese in system settings, the app will show resources using Chinese. Localization works in app itself, the settings bundle, and the app name in home screen. (And of course, if system is set to English, my app will show English resources)

However, when running it on 3GS + OS4.0, it always shows English resource no matter what language I choose in system settings. The app itself always shows English, settings bundle is in English, and app name in Home screen shows the English version too.

I tried many things such as restart the device, reinstall the app, add CFBundleLocalizations  in info.plist, etc. No help.

What have I done wrong that might cause the localization to fail on OS4.0 (although still works on 3.x)?

Here's my localization folder structure, which I believe is very normal:

```
+---en.lproj
|       InfoPlist.strings
|       Localizable.strings
|
\---zh.lproj
        InfoPlist.strings
        Localizable.strings
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Try to rename that to `zh_CN.lproj` (or `zh_TW.lproj`). Does that help?

Comment: Thanks Kenny. It actually works by adding the _CN/_TW suffix. So for now I can solve this problem.

However I can't find any Apple doc that mention this change. in 3.0, "zh" alone works fine, and both CN and TW users will see the same set of chinese resources. But in 4.0, we have to add regional IDs?

According to apple doc, iPhone OS should solely look at language-id-only lproj, such as zh.lproj. See http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Articles/LanguageDesignations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002144-BBCEGGFF