# Can't automatically load localized resources with pathForResource

Tags: iphone, html, objective-c, localization

I've got an iPhone app that need to be localized. 
No problem with strings, but, I'm having trouble with resources : I need to load HTML pages that are localized.
The files are like : presentation.htm 
The files are added in the project with the folder where they are (html/), and it add the group called as the folder.

I load the html pages with this code :

```
NSString *pathPresentation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"presentation" ofType:@"htm"];

if(!pathPresentation) {
    NSLog(@"Could not find presentation.htm");
}
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathPresentation];
NSLog(@"-> path presentation.htm : %@", pathPresentation);
UIWebView *webViewPresentation = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
NSData *htmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:pathPresentation];  
if (htmlData) {  
    [webViewPresentation loadData:htmlData MIMEType:@"text/html" textEncodingName:@"Latin-1" baseURL:url];  
}
```

**First Try :**

I've followed the indications of this website [I Can Localize](http://www.icanlocalize.com/site/tutorials/iphone-applications-localization-guide/), since there was yet localized resources in the app. 
The folders are named : *en.lproj* and *fr.lproj*.

I try it on the simulator, but it didn't succeed :

- the log indicates that the path is : (...)/myapp.app/presentation.htm
- the file loaded in the simulator is in french, while the simulator is in english.

---

**Second Try :**

Then, I delete the resources and re-add them in their group folder (Resource/html/). I pressed the Info button, and choose to "Make file localizable".
The file was added in a *English.lproj* folder. 
Then I choose "Add Localization", and "French".

I try it on the simulator, but it didn't succeed (I have clean the build before testing) :

- the log indicates that the path is : (...)/myapp.app/presentation.htm
- the file loaded in the simulator is in french, while the simulator is in english.

---

**Third Try :**

After reading [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3125808/running-on-iphone-os-4-0-my-app-no-longer-loads-localized-resource) about loading localized resources on iPhone OS 4.0, I've changed the resources in localized folders (delete resources, and rename folders in *en_UK.lproj* and *fr_FR.lproj*

I try it on the simulator, but it didn't succeed (I have clean the build before testing) :

- the log indicates that the path is : (...)/myapp.app/presentation.htm
- the file loaded in the simulator is in french, while the simulator is in english.

---

**Help ?**

Any idea ? 
I know there is the function : 
`- (NSString *)pathForResource:(NSString *)name ofType:(NSString *)extension inDirectory:(NSString *)subpath forLocalization:(NSString *)localizationName`

But I want it to be as automatic as possible, and fixing things like Directory or localizationName may prevent my app to be automatic.

Comment: After removing the app from the simulator, it didn't work, but the path has changed. Now it is : (...)/myapp.app/fr_FR.lproj/presentation.htm

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The solution is :

1. remove application from simulator (or device)
2. use simple localized folders, as : *en.lproj*
3. clean build

Comment: Do this! After trying every solution to no effect, of course the hard reset worked.

Comment: I wish I had found this post before I had spent two hours. For me the "remove application" was the trick. I guess it gets confused.

Comment: Simulator reset and clean install worked on second attempt. Doing it once wasn't enough :)

Comment: What the f…! Working in Xcode 5 and for iOS 7 this silly workaround is still needed. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, literally had to reset twice